# How to send POST request via angular's HttpClient?

Tags: angular

I want to send POST request via angular's HttpClient.

This is my typescript code:

```
saveEvent() {
        let header = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        return this.http.post(this.eventUrl, JSON.stringify(this.data), { headers: header });
}
```

And my HTML code:

```
<button (click)="saveEvent()">Click me!</button>
```

I have no any forms, just want send JSON to server via POST-request. Request is not sent as I see at chrome console. How to fix this?

Comment: post the code where you invoke saveEvent

Comment: Do you ever `.subscribe` to it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe No.

Comment: Then that's likely the problem, no? Per [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#always-subscribe): *"An `HttpClient` method does not begin its HTTP request until you call `subscribe()` on the observable returned by that method."* You could use `| async`, or subscribe explicitly in the class and expose the *result* to the template.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things here.

1. It is not a good practice to make http requests from event handlers. Makes your component less conducive to unit testing.
2. There is no subscription.

Here is how the code ought to look like.

a. Your component which has the template.

```html
<button (click)="saveEvent()">Click me!</button>
```

b. Your component class code, which will have a constructor and the dependency injected of a service provider

```
saveEvent(): void{

  this._serviceProvider.PostData(this.data)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    //Show Some Message. Say pop a dialog/modal confirming the data save.
  })
```

}

c. The code in the service provider that posts the data and makes the actual HTTP call.

```
public PostData(data: any): Observable<any> {


            //Check if you need access tokens. Usually posts need access tokens. 
             let access_token: string = "";

            let url: string = "https://YourPostDataUrl/PostdataEndPoint";
            let headers = new Headers({
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            });

            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

            return this._http.post(url, data, options)
                .map(res => res.json())
                .catch(this.handleError)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to subscribe to any HTTP request, including post to make it work. Your code just declares your intention to perform the post request. Here's an example where I do HTTP POST of a form:

https://github.com/Farata/angulartypescript/blob/master/code-samples/chapter12/client/src/app/restclientpost/app.component.ts